# Swift 1.2 -> Swift 2 Conversion time

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7-beta4

Has anyone converted an app from 1.2 to Swift 2?  My app is small - about 1k LOC, and its been converting for >2 hours now.  I'm stuck on the following screen:

[image: screen]([![enter image description here]

How long should I expect this to take?  Thanks...

Comment: If you cancel and start the migration with Console open, does anything useful print to the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift compiler has an issue with arrays. I have commented out all the elements of the array (like 10x UIColor), left only one element and conversion went smoothly.

Here's how you can debug the issue in your project:

1. Got to the Report navigator (CMD + 8)
2. Build your app, select the latest build and watch log (select `All Messages` filter)
3. The problematic file will be stuck on the compile status.
4. Navigate to that file and figure out what can hang the compiler (probably arrays/dictionaries).

Why build not convert? Because it's verbose.

Answer (score 4):

The process **is** long, but it shouldn't take more than several minutes.
The Swift converter is probably having an issue (e.g.: some kind of infinite loop).

You should abort and try to find what happened or maybe migrate manually.

Comment: I aborted, restarted xcode-beta, unchecked the "tests" target, and then re-initialized the conversion process. After that, it went real nice n smooth